# How to test java(Elasticsearch) service?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, junit

I use Java 8, Elastic 6.1, Rest High level client  for searching and adding information(logs and metrics).
Right know I need to test this service, methods for adding and saving information(like with the help of Junit4).
I have found  documentation for this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/testing-framework.html, but don't exactly understand how to do it and from what to start.
For example, I have such code for adding logs:

```
@Override
    public void addLogsToES(ElasticSearchLogs elasticSearchLogs) throws NoConnectionException {
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date()).toLowerCase();
        XContentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .field("timeStamp", elasticSearchLogs.getTimeStamp())
                    .field("header", elasticSearchLogs.getHeader())
                    .field("type", elasticSearchLogs.getType())
                    .field("message", elasticSearchLogs.getMessage())
                    .field("level", elasticSearchLogs.getLevel())
                    .field("node", elasticSearchLogs.getNode())
                    .field("system", elasticSearchLogs.getSystem())
                    .field("version", elasticSearchLogs.getVersion())
                    .field("port", elasticSearchLogs.getPort())
                    .field("service", elasticSearchLogs.getService())
                    .field("module", elasticSearchLogs.getModule())
                    .field("submodule", elasticSearchLogs.getSubmodule())
                    .field("thread", elasticSearchLogs.getThread())
                    .field("operation", elasticSearchLogs.getOperation())
                    .field("sessionId", elasticSearchLogs.getSessionId())
                    .field("userLogin", elasticSearchLogs.getUserLogin())
                    .field("userName", elasticSearchLogs.getUserName())
                    .field("office", elasticSearchLogs.getOffice())
                    .field("location", elasticSearchLogs.getLocation())
                    .field("ip", elasticSearchLogs.getIp())
                    .field("device", elasticSearchLogs.getDevice())
                    .field("metricType", elasticSearchLogs.getMetricType())
                    .field("value", elasticSearchLogs.getValue())
                    .endObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new NoConnectionException("No connection to Elasticsearch", e);
        }

        if (elasticSearchLogs.getSystem().equals("front-admin")
                           && (elasticSearchLogs.getTimeStamp() == null
                           || elasticSearchLogs.getOperation() == null
                           || elasticSearchLogs.getValue() == null || elasticSearchLogs.getValue() == null)) {
                       throw new IllegalArgumentException("elastic.metricValueEmpty");
                   }
            IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("portal-logs-" + date,
                    "logs_info").source(builder);
            bulkProcessor.add(indexRequest);
    }
```

From what I should start?

Comment: But whitch part of testing reference guide you dont understand?

Comment: I found how to create an integrational tests, but I coudn't found how to test my service methods. Do I need to create integrational tests for testing my service methods?

Comment: You should test your service method with without using elasticsearch imho, only mocks. If you want to test elasticsearch trough services, than it will be integration test anyway as this will test **integration** between services and es

Comment: I want to test ES through services with integration tests but can't find right example for Rest client.

Comment: Again, that would be integration test.